# Where is the best place to define enums in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am writing a model class for my application and I am wondering where I should define an enum that the class will use. Should it be in the class or outside of it?

Comment: In Swift, it's not as simple as "in the class or outside of it". Research the nonstandard behavior of Swift's private modifier, and extensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nest the enum, or make it private, based on the rules below. There should never be any reason to use the clunky **CE** syntax that Objective-C required.

```
class C {}

// Do this if you need E outside C.
extension C {
  enum E {

  }
}

private enum E {} // Do this if you won't use E outside this file.
```

Comment: Why do we make the enum an extension of C rather than define it inside the class?

Comment: That works too. You just can't cut the exact code out of the file and move it elsewhere. This method works inside the same file as the parent type definition, or outside.

Answer (score 10):

If only the one class uses the enum, then you should define it inside your class. But if more then one class uses your enum, you should create it in it's own file.

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, please accept my answer, so that other people can find it easier. :)

Comment: Haha you answered so fast that it didn't allow me to accept for another 11 minutes.

Comment: Where does this logic come from?

Comment: @Jessy Personal knowledge and object-oriented thinking. There is no complete wrong or right answer, but I think it is the 'clean' and oo-way to code.

Comment: "in its own file" does not mean that the enum can't be nested, due to extensions.